# Teradata regular expressions, look behind

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I have a field, Simplified_Description and I'm looking for patterns in it.  Specifically, I'm looking for a pattern like 6 X 8 or 6X8 or 600X800.  I want to pull out the first and second numbers into new fields.  I've been able to get the first number (with much help) using a look-ahead.

```
REGEXP_substr(Simplified_Description, '[0-9]+(?= {0,1}[X] {0,1}[0-9]+)') AS FirstNum,
```

When I try to get the second number by changing the look-ahead to a look-behind (by simply adding in a "<"),

```
REGEXP_substr(Simplified_Description, '[0-9]+(?<= {0,1}[X] {0,1}[0-9]+)') AS SecondNum
```

I now get an error

```
SELECT Failed.   [9134] The pattern specified is not a valid pattern.
```

I am a complete newb on regular expressions, especially on look-ahead and look-behind, so it's possible I have some extremely simple error, but I can't figure it out as what I'm doing appears to be the correct syntax.

Comment: Try `'\d+\s*X\s*\K\d+'`

Comment: you can try [`(?<first>\d+)\s*X\s*(?<second>\d+) `](https://regex101.com/r/12fuv4/1)to get separate groups for each value in one regex only

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works, although now I have to try to understand this :)  These regular expressions appear to be as confusing as they are powerful.

Comment: @mquantin That is very cool, although I'm not sure how to use that in Teradata.  In Teradata, if I use that, I get the full expression only, e.g., 6X8.

Comment: @Graphth: You do not have to decipher my solutions, I always explain them if they work in my answers. Let me know via comments if anything is still unclear.

Comment: good question, I don't use teradata! :D ...  maybe this function `(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE (source_string, regexp_string, match_arg)`.  "This table function splits a source string into a table of strings using a regular expression as the delimiter."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see that.  I guess I'm saying that simple regular expressions can do quite a bit, but there appears to be so much available that if I were to know them well, it would take quite a bit of learning.  Your answer and explanation will help with the learning process.

Comment: @mquantin Using what you said with a bit of googling, it appears it is possible to use this.  I will keep this in mind.  Thanks so much for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex to extract the first number:

```
REGEXP_substr(Simplified_Description, '\d+(?=\s*X\s*\d)') AS FirstNum
```

and this regex for the second number:

```
REGEXP_substr(Simplified_Description, '\d+\s*X\s*\K\d+') AS SecondNum
```

See the [regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/JMpuLt/1) and [regex 2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV8Cda/1).

**Patter 1 details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits that are followed with...
- `(?=\s*X\s*\d)` - a sequence of patterns:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `X` - an `X` char
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d` - a digit.

**Pattern 2 details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s*X\s*` - an `X` char enclosed with any 0+ whitespace chars
- `\K`  -  a [match reset operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) that omits (removes) the text matched so far from the match value
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: The `\K` is nice, easier than a lookbehind :-)

Comment: @dnoeth It allows a variable width pattern before the matched part. However, `\K` does not allow overlapping matches, that is only possible with a variable-width lookbehind, as in .NET or Python PyPi regex.